# How to display foreignkey causing a ProtectedError?

Tags: django, django-views

When django throws a `ProtectedError` (because `on_delete=models.PROTECT` in some model field), it runs [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/deletion/) source code to render the response:

```
class ProtectedError(IntegrityError):
    def __init__(self, msg, protected_objects):
        self.protected_objects = protected_objects
        super().__init__(msg, protected_objects)

    def PROTECT(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
        raise ProtectedError(
            "Cannot delete some instances of model '%s' because they are "
            "referenced through a protected foreign key: '%s.%s'" % (
                field.remote_field.model.__name__, sub_objs[0].__class__.__name__, 
                field.name
            ),
            sub_objs
        )
```

When handling this error, I know it's easy enough to override  `delete()` on the view:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    try:
        self.object.delete()
        messages.error(self.request, 'Ok')
    except ProtectedError:
        messages.error(self.request, 'Whoops')
    return HttpResponse('myurl')
```

However, I'd like to be more specific in the message I pass. How can I access `field.remote_field.model.__name__`, `sub_objs[0].__class__.__name__`, and `field.name` from the `PROTECT` function in my view?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to get the information you want from the PROTECT function other than extracting it from the generated message with some regular expression stuff.

What is possible to create your own subclass of the ProtectedError and your own PROTECT method, e.g.:

```
class MyProtectError(models.deletion.ProtectedError):

    def __init__(self, msg, protected_objects, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        super().__init__(msg, protected_objects)

def MY_PROTECT(collector, field, sub_objs, using):
    kwargs = {
        'field': field,
        'sub_objs': sub_objs,
        'using': using
    }
    raise MyProtectError(
        "Cannot delete some instances of model '%s' because they are "
        "referenced through a protected foreign key: '%s.%s'" % (
            field.remote_field.model.__name__, sub_objs[0].__class__.__name__, field.name
        ),
        sub_objs, **kwargs
    )
```

Then use the `MY_PROTECT` in your model, e.g.

```
class ProtectChild(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    master = models.ForeignKey(ProtectMaster, on_delete=MY_PROTECT)
```

and use your custom class in your overwritten `delete()` method:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        try:
            self.object.delete()
            messages.error(self.request, 'Ok')
        except MyProtectError as e:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Whoops')
            print('Model', e.kwargs['field'].remote_field.model.__name__)
            print('Field', e.kwargs['field'].name)
            print('Submodel', e.kwargs['sub_objs'][0].__class__.__name__)
        return render(request, 'myurl')
```